# How to use EnvironmentName in .Net Core 2.0 Console application?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

What is a proper name for .Net Core 2.0 environment parameter? My app does not use Asp.net, it is just console service app.
How to load proper config for an environment in a console application?

Currently, I use the following code. How to improve it?

```
var envConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .Build();
var environmentName = envConfig["ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"];
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json")
    .Build();
```

Comment: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is an environment variable specifically used for switching between different configurations in an ASP.NET Core web service.    if you're not using ASP.NET, then what do you actually need this environment variable for?

Comment: And how do you control which environment this app is in? Do you pass something to starutp arguments?

Comment: @Evk I just run `set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` before run my console service on dev machine. On server I have ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production in system environment.

Comment: @BenCottrell I need same environment switch as NODE_ENV in node.js. As you can see in my sample, I use it to extend configuration files.

Comment: @AlexeyRyazhskikh what exactly you want to improve? If you just don't want to use additional `ConfigurationBuilder envConfig` and always planning to determine env based on `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`  then simply read the value directly using `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")`